# Describe attractors of a finite family of contraction mappings

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals

The question is to describe the attractor of iterated function system $\mathcal{F}=\{R^2,f_1,f_2\},$ where $f_1,f_2$ are the two affine transformations$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0.8\\
    -0.5&0 \\\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    y \\\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0.5\\\end{bmatrix}$;$\begin{bmatrix}
    0.7 & 0\\
    0&0.6 \\\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    y \\\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    0.6\\
    0.4\\\end{bmatrix}$.
Here $f_1$ and $f_2$ are contraction mappings , hence there must be an unique compact set $B \subset R^2$ which satisfies $ B=f_1(B)\bigcup f_2(B) $ . My question is , how to find this $B?$ I've tried to use the fact that $B=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f_1\bigcup f_2)^n(X)$ for any compact set $X\subset R^2$. However, the calculation is tedious and I couldn't find the result.
Is there any convenient way to find the attractor?

Comment: What form would you want the answer in?  I was always under the impression that all you can do is use a computer to draw out the fractal (looks like if you google iterated function system java, there are some applets for this).  You might want to know if $B$ is in some family of fractals, or maybe you want to write each point of $B$ as the image of a mapping from the sequence of functions $\{f_1,f_2\}^\mathbb{N}$ to a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Do you know if either these or something better is possible?

Comment: @tagb78:  what does IFS stand for?  Also, how does this dynamical system *work*, exactly?   I am confused because each of your maps is of the general form $Ax + b$, where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $b$ a $2 \times 1$ vector.  How do these act in concert to produce your desired map, which I presume is from $R^2 \to R^2$ (is it in fact?)?  Cool question, though.  +1!

Comment: @tgb78:  what do we do, iterate by choosing one of the $f_i$ at each stage according to some, perhaps probabilistic, recipe?  Thanks again . . .

Answer (score 0):

The attractor is the union of the red and blue portions shown here:

[image]

The red portion is $f_1(B)$ and the blue portion is $f_2(B)$.  As suggested in the comments, I generated the image on a computer.  There is still quite a lot that can be determined analytically, however. The attractor is totally disconnected, for example.  The convex hull can also be determined, as illustrated in the diagram.  The extreme point in the upper right is the fixed point of $f_2$, namely $x_0=(2,1)$, while the other extreme points are $f_1(x_0)$, $f_1^2(x_0)$, $f_1^3(x_0)$, and $f_2^k(f_1^3(x_0))$, where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$.